# using ui-view lead to Failed to instantiate module ui.router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning Angularjs and I am trying to structure this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/T9J7bz?p=preview)
over different files and using  **ui-view**.

So here is my **app.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Main', []);

angular.module('plunker', ['angularCharts', 'Main', 'ui.router']);

angular.module('plunker').config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: '',
            templateUrl: 'main.html',
        })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('app')
});
```

my **index.html** with ui-view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Angular-charts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.2" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.2"></script>
    <script data-require="d3@*" data-semver="3.3.11" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.11/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/chinmaymk/angular-charts/bower/dist/angular-charts.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <script src="controllers.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div ui-view=""></div>
</body>

</html>
```

my **controller**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Main').controller('MainCntrl', [

function MainCtrl($scope) {
    ...
}]);
```

But when I run my project, I am getting this error in the console log:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module plunker due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.router due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.router' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.2/$injector/nomod?p0=ui.router
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:78:12
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:1522:17
    at ensure (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:1447:38)
    at module (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:1520:14)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:3544:22
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:300:11)
    at loadModules (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:3538:5)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:3545:40
    at Array.forEach (native)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=ui.router&p1=Error%…F1.2.2%2Fangular.js%3A3545%3A40%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20(native)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:78:12
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:3572:15
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:300:11)
    at loadModules (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:3538:5)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:3545:40
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:300:11)
    at loadModules (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:3538:5)
    at createInjector (https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js:3478:11)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=plunker&p1=Error%3A…ector%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.2.2%2Fangular.js%3A3478%3A11)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you have to inject ui-router

Comment: `ui-view` is directive of the `ui-router` module to use it you will have to source it and then inject it in the module

Comment: other than that you can't do `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('app')` as you don't have state with url with `app`

Comment: how can I inject the ui-router?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router) for `ui.router` states that it must be injected as a dependency in the application:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['angularCharts', 'Main', 'ui.router']);
```

You also need to refactor your route configuration properly:

```
angular.module('plunker').config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            // The url needs to be defined as a directory
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'main.html',
        })
    // Redirect to the '/app' route.
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app')
});
```

This assumes you have included `angular-ui-router.js` as a script in your index page.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.17/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

Comment: I noticed you hadn't included `angular-ui-router.js` in your index page. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: angular-ui-router.js fixes it, but now I have Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: This is a different question. 

You'll need to check the name of your controller. It's called `MainCntrl` where it was created. This means there is no such controller named `MainCtrl`. I don't know if that's what you intended.

Comment: thanks @gnerkus, after fixing another couple of errors I managed to run the app