# "Failed to instantiate module ui.router"

Tags: angularjs

The problem is simple and the answer is probably pretty obvious but I really can't find out what's going wrong here.

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/12crh8er/)

As you can see, no links are generated and no views are loaded.

I have looked into related problems aswell (e.g [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159775/using-ui-view-lead-to-failed-to-instantiate-module-ui-router)) but it wasn't much of a use.

*index.html*

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="#">AngularUI Router</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <p>This is the Home Page</p>    
  </div>
</script>
```

*app.js*

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
        });

}]);
```

**EDIT**

I should have mentioned that I included [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) in the External Resources tab in my fiddle.

This is what gets generated by JSFiddle:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="routerApp">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="#">AngularUI Router</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <div ui-view=""></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
      <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p>This is the Home Page</p>
      </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[

      var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

      routerApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

        $stateProvider
          .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
          });

      }]);
      //]]>

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT #2**

It seems like this was a problem with JSFiddle's External Resources rather than ui-router.

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/12crh8er/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include angular-ui-router in your index.html

You can for example add:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/12crh8er/1/)

Comment: @Pascal it's most likely a problem with how jsfiddle loads external resources. It seems that using that section makes the ui.router dependency loads after than your js code, so when it loads it doesn't know what ui.router is

Comment: @Pascal it works even if you load it manually in the `<head>` of your page, like you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/12crh8er/4/) so I suspect it's just a jsfiddle thing.

Answer (score 2):

ui.router is a separate module. You need to download it and include a script, e.g. download from [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases)

There is a default angular router, but that one probably should be added as a separate script as well.

Comment: You mean http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.min.js?

Comment: E.g., but you can just download it and serve from local. Updated the answer with the reference to the github.

Comment: It seems it is not adding it. Try checking your network tab if you see it. You can try to add the reference directly in html instead of relying on the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Angular [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) is a client-side Single Page Application routing framework for AngularJS.Routing frameworks for SPAs(Single Page Applications) update the browser's URL as the user navigates through the app.

[Check this](https://jsfiddle.net/3vhwnur4/) fiddle

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
    }).state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'about.html'
    });
```

Comment: @Pascal change your ui.router URL to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.js